# Passing directory with space as command line argument in FileReader in java

Tags: java, exception, command-line, directory, filereader

```
try (BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        System.out.println("Reading from file :" + args[0]);
        String s = null;
        while ((s = b.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        System.out.println("No file specified, quitting !");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println("File not found :" + args[0]);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file : " + ie.getMessage());
    }
```

here args[0] is : G:\Lab Practice\file.txt

**output:**
File not found :G:\Lab

This is because there is a space in the path.
I've also tried replacing args[0] with args[0]+args[1] but it didn't work.
Could anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried passing your args in double quotes, i.e. `"G:\Lab Practice\file.txt"`?

Comment: "here args[0] is : G:\Lab Practice\file.txt" - no, it's not. `args[0]` is `"G:\\Lab"`.  You need to escape the command-line argument when you invoke Java. On windows there are many options, the simples one is to put double quotes around the whole path. See https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you call your program like so:

```
java -jar application.jar G:\Lab Practice\file.txt
```

This simply means you have two arguments - `G:\Lab` (in `args[0]`) and `Practice\file.txt` (in `args[1]`). Both now without any spaces.

You need to put some quotes in the call:

```
java -jar application.jar "G:\Lab Practice\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply just put the argument in quotes:

```
java Class "G:\Lab Practice\file.txt"
```

Without the space, it treats each one as separate argument in the `args` array - so `G:\Lab` is `args[0]` and `Practice\file.txt` is `args[1]` in your example.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html):

> This is because the space character separates command-line arguments.
>   To have Drink, Hot, and Java interpreted as a single argument, the
>   user would join them by enclosing them within quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the path argument in quotes - e.g.

```
java com.your.application.Main "G:\Lab Practice\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use quotes?

like: `args[0] is : "G:\Lab Practice\file.txt"`

Comment: Thank you it worked. I thought command line arguments need not be given within quotes but for a directory, this works.